# Set size 'gridcolumn' by content in ExtJS

Tags: gridview, extjs

I have a gridview with columns. Here example :

```
 {
     xtype: 'gridcolumn',
     header: '№',                   
     dataIndex: 'number'
 },
```

Is there any way to autosize column **by content**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes just use the flex property.

Example:

```
column1 flex: 1  column2: flex: 1

|-----Column 1-----|-----Column 2-----|

column1 flex: 2  column2: flex: 1

|--------Column 1--------|--Column 2--|
```

Comment: Ok, it's work! But, I want to add  size  column by content. Have you got idea about it?

Comment: Mark this guy's answer as correct and post another question to stack overflow.  The second thing you asked in the comment is completely different to do.

Comment: I only can edit my question, because it's can't be duplicated.